# Running a java class that requries jar files

Tags: classpath

Usually I package my small application (2-3 classes) into a jar file. The dependent libraries (other jars) are added to the manifest file.
But this time since I had just one class file. I decided to keep the class file as it is and tried to run it.
So I had my one class file and all the jar files in the same folder and I tried to run the class file

1)java MyClass
To my surprise it couldn't find the jar files

2) java -classpath "pathtoonejar" MyClass
Now it said can't find MyClass itself :)

3)java -classpath ".;pathtoonejar" MyClass
Now it can't find classes that are included in other jars

4) So, java -classpath ".;pathtoonejar;jartwo.jar;jarthree.jar" MyClass

Is this the right way , and the only way I can run my Class file.
Comm'on , I find this really weird. First in statement 2, java can't find the class file in the same directory itself.
Also I tried to put all jars in one lib directory and tried

5) java -classpath ".;lib/*.jar" MyClass
This did not work too.

So is 4 the only right way of running the class file.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try java -classpath "*" myPackage\MyClass

where myPackage is the name of the package of your class.

Here is a [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)